# Allow/Escape spaces in Linux PAM modules

Tags: linux, parsing, ldap, escaping, pam

I am running into an issue we have with Active Directory and PAM, but this can apply elsewhere.

Setting up Yubikey over PAM to utilize two-factor authentication with VPN connections, I need to set a binddn to the bind user who contacts the AD/LDAP server.  Unfortunately there is a container in the binddn that has a space in it, and PAM does not allow for this space, nor does it let me escape it.  Example:

```
/etc/pam.d/radiusd

auth       required     pam_yubico.so id=16 debug ldap_uri=ldap://ad-server.local ldapdn=DC=company,DC=local binddn=CN=binduser,OU=users,OU=other accounts,OU=departments,DC=company,DC=local bindpw=5up3rpa55w0rd user_attr=sAMAccountName yubi_attr=employeeNumber
```

I've tried OU="other accounts", OU=other\ accounts, OU='other accounts', and putting the entire binddn in double and single quotes.  Every time in the PAM debug, I get this:

```
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(747)] called.
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(748)] flags 0 argc 9
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[0]=id=16
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[1]=debug
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[2]=ldap_uri=ldap://ad-server.local
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[3]=ldapdn=DC=company,DC=local
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[4]=binddn=CN=binduser,OU=users,OU=other
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[5]=accounts,OU=departments,DC=company,DC=local
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[6]=bindpw=5up3rpa55w0rd 
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[7]=user_attr=sAMAccountName
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[8]=yubi_attr=employeeNumber
```

As you can see, it gets cut off after the space, quotes or escape characters are seen in the list as part of the binddn like so:

```
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[4]=binddn=CN=binduser,OU=users,OU=other\
[pam_yubico.c:parse_cfg(750)] argv[5]=accounts,OU=departments,DC=company,DC=local
```

What can I do to get PAM to recognize that this space isn't to separate another field?

Comment: Try `ou=other%20accounts,` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it takes %20 literally as well, but it does keep the line together:


CN=binduser,OU=users,OU=other%20accounts,OU=departments,DC=company,DC=local

Comment: That's a valid DN, escaped correctly (from an LDAP point of view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the useful documentation available by typing `man pam.d`: (emphasis added)

> *module-arguments* are a space separated list of tokens that can be used to modify the specific behavior of the given PAM. Such arguments will be documented for each individual module. Note, if you wish to include spaces in an argument, you should **surround that argument with square brackets**.

The following text includes some notes about how to deal with arguments which contain square brackets, and an example line.

Comment: I found the same result from one last search on this subject:
[PAM Configuration guide for Debian](http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-pam-debian.php) just after I posted the question and couldn't answer myself.  Thanks.